# В конце блока добавляется "1" при подключении PHP-файла

Tags: php, html

При использовании `include 'text.php'` в конце каждого блока добавляет *"1"*.

Для страницы получается так:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- Нижняя часть страницы -->
            <?= include_once 'inc/bottom.inc.php' ?>
            <!-- Нижняя часть страницы -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?= drawMenu($leftmenu, $vertical); ?>
<hr>
&copy; Супер Мега Веб-мастер, 2000 &ndash; <?= $year ?>`
```

Вывод:

> © Супер Мега Веб-мастер, 2000 – 20151

Делаю тест *include*:

```
<?php
   echo '<h1>BEFORE</h1>';
   include_once "test.inc.php";
   echo '<h1>AFTER</h1>';
 ?>
```

*test.inc.php*:

```
<h2>INCLUDED!</h2>
```

Вывод нормальный.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте `<?=` на `<?`. Вы делает `echo` тому, что возвращает `include_once`.

А возвращает он `true`, которое преобразуется в `1`.